# issue with validation two columns at once

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent

I have an issue with validation by two columns in laravel

I have table **work_hours** with `user_id` and date and hours and I have more than one user so I need to give user opportunities to add his hours but only once for a specific date for example

Add 8 hours on 28-03-2018 for `user_id = 9`, but only once so If user try add once again Add 8 hours on 28-03-2018 for `user_id = 9` He has information this date has already taken.

I wrote validation:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'date' => 'unique:work_hours',
            'name_of_hours' => 'required',
        ]);
```

but this work that if somebody of users Add 8 hours on 28-03-2018 for `user_id = 9`, `user_id=10` or another can't add hours on this same date.

So, I need validation for two columns at once, `user_id` and date but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good case for closures.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'date' => function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            // check the table for the date and current user
            $date = DB::table('work_hours')->where([
                ['date', $value],
                ['user_id', Auth::user()->id]
            ])->first();
            // if it exists then you fail
            if ($date) $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
        },
        'name_of_hours' => 'required',
    ]);
```

You can review the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#using-closures

Comment: Thank You, query looks very good, because I have `select
  *
from
  work_hours
where
  (
    date = "2019-03-05"
    and user_id = 9
  )
limit
  1` but I don't have hours for this user_id at 05-03-2018 but I have `{"errors":["date is invalid."]}`

Comment: I was using a bang, but edited my answer. Sorry about that! instead of if ( ! $date ) it should be if ( $date ) -- only if it's true then you fail, otherwise, it's false and the entry was not found